# Missing argument 1 for any() on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-blade

I'm new to laravel and i'm getting

> Missing argument 1 for any(), called in C:\wamp64\www\NewLaravel\storage\framework\views\0076eaa92b4bf0f347725a7d763fec50e12a8006.php on line 4 and defined (View: C:\wamp64\www\NewLaravel\resources\views\posts\add.blade.php)

Here I'm sending the user to a new page to add data. I'm not passing and variables here 
When user clicks on add New button it takes him to `posts/add.blade.php` page.

Route web.php

`Route::get('/posts/add', 'PostsController@add')->name('posts.add');`

PostsController

```
public function add(){
    //load form view
    return view('posts.add');
}
```

view file : `resource/views/posts/add.blade.php`

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        @if($errors>any())
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                    <p>{{$error}}</p>
                @endforeach
                </div>
        @endif

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Add New Post <a href="{{route('posts.index')}}" class="label label-primary pull-right">Back</a> 
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body"></div>
```

### THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: You're missing a hyphen, so you're asking if `$errors` is greater than `any()`

Comment: `$errors->any()`. See the `-`?

Comment: it's ok , hypen need to add after error.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `if-endif` codeblock in your view as below:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Refer this [Laravel CRUD Article](http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/crud-create-read-update-delete-example-in-laravel-52-from-scratchexample.html)